# Should I rename package after Android app name change?

Tags: programming-practices, git, android

I have an Android app.

I have changed the app's name from `appname1` to `appname2`. I would like to know if I should also change my package name from `com.myname.appname1` to `com.myname.appname2` to reflect the app name change?

The advantage of also changing the package name is that everything is consistent. But the disadvantage is that Git will treat such renaming of package as deletion and addition of files; and this makes looking at changes difficult.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git should treat renaming a folder as files moved around the place (whether or not you use the `git mv` command).

The other problem of changing the name of package is that users of the application won't get it as an update but as a new application. If it's a paid app, it can be annoying. If it's a free app, they may not notice the new version and your downloads could suffer from it.

Comment: If my app is in the final stage of development and has not been released yet, is it worth the hassle of renaming the package after I change the name of the app? Does it bother you that the package name and the app name are not consistent?

Comment: As a developer, it bothers me when the package name is inconsistent whether it's for my own apps or on the PlayStore. But I'm not sure that end users actually care about it.

Comment: If it hasn't even been released, I would make the names consistent now (as @d311404 said, git can handle it) so that there's one less weird thing to potentially confuse you later on when you need to make big changes without breaking anything.

Comment: What does it mean to say "git can handle it"? It seems to me git handles file renaming in a way that does not allow me to compare code before and after the name change.

Comment: It can "handle it" in the sense that its heuristics for detecting when files have moved are pretty good. Not all git commands will do that move detection by default, but once you know how to enable it with options like `git diff -M` it's pretty easy to work with.